# Relay indicator light

Tags: led, relay, indicator

I feel a bit silly asking this..

I have a relay, which has a switch that turns it on/off.
Next to the switch I have an indicator light which needs to turn on when the switch is turned on.

I tried putting the LED in parallel (seen below) and in line, but no luck.

[image]
What am I missing here?

*(by the way, the 22k resistor is a good value for this LED at this voltage)*

Comment: Your LED and 22k resistor look shorted.

Comment: In your diagram, the LED is providing a very high resistance path in parallel to a section of unbroken wire. How is this supposed to cause current to flow through the LED?

Comment: It *might* work if you connect the LED and resistor parallel to the relay's switching coil (I.E. LED attached before coil, resistor attaches after it.)

Comment: @Robher KV5ROB; Yes, that did the trick. Although I'm not fully understanding why.

Comment: That's doing the trick because the back-emf of the relay switching coil is a voltage potential, while the negative resistance of the wire you connected to has a virtually 0 voltage potential. Because of that, you have now created a parallel circuit between the LED+resistor combo & the relay's switchign circuit (both see ~24V, where before the switching coil was seeing 24V & the LED+resistor were seeing ~0.0001v at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm0gRB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 will allow approximately 20 mA through the LED.
D2 protects the LED from the transient when the relay is turned off. D2 could go directly across the relay coil but it does not have to.

Comment: This works, so in the end my change was to move the positive from after the coil to straight from the source before the coil. The diode is a good idea though.

Comment: However; I still am not really understanding why the original circuit didn't work. Apparently there is not enough current (?) left after the coil, not even when I lower the resistor value for the LED. -- Or does this has something to do with the mentioned impedence of the power supply? (I don't really know what that means)  -- Thing is, having to power the LED straight from the power supply is another wire in an already very tight enclosure. I was hoping to power the LED straight from the switch.

Comment: The "Power Supply" in the field will be two big 12V batteries / 90A generator.. Not sure if that changes anything...

Comment: @svenema Your original schematic has a dead short across the resistor & LED. The current will take the (essentially) 0 ohm path instead of going through the LED.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsGSCk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Youll want to double check your resistor value

You may also want to add a back emf protection diode, as seen here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMjITh.png)</sup>

Comment: as @RobhercKV5ROB hinted, this will depend on how "good" your power supply is (i.e. how low it's output resistance is).

Comment: but if everything works without the led there, then the led should light up correctly when you put it in.

Comment: out of interest, have you measured the resistance of your relay?

Comment: ok, it's a bit weird.. I would expect this circuit to work as you draw it, but it's not. 

at just +24V -> LED -> 22k resistor -> NEG, this works fine
when I throw in the relay, the LED won't turn on anymore

I think the resistance might be too high.. perhaps at this voltage transistors are required?

Comment: resistance of the relay is 330 ohm

Comment: What's probably happening is that the impedance of your power supply is quite high, and the resistance of your relay is quite low. This is lowering the output voltage of your supply. What are you using as a supply?

Comment: @BeB00 if V1 is powered off depending on D1 ratings it might blow up isn't it?

Comment: @BeB00, it's a bench power supply, Gophert CPS 3205.. when it works it will go into a 24V vehicle

Comment: @HervéGrabas I'm not quite sure what you mean, but in this configuration D1 should never blow up

Comment: @svenema can you measure the voltage across your relay when you turn it on? I'm a bit surprised, as you are only drawing 70mA. however, how big is your relay? It looks like it will be putting out 1.7W of heat, which is quite a bit

Comment: @BeB00 assume V1 suddenly goes to 0V. Then all the sudden D1 sees 24V reverse voltage no?

Comment: @HervéGrabas thats a good point, although actually what would happen is that if v1 suddenly went open circuit, D1 would actually see a high forward voltage, which might break it. When you turn off the switch, you may get a high reverse voltage, so i edited my answer